# Looking for a good online book for shemira einayim

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, see-sight-vision-blind

anyone know of a good reliable online book for studying the matter of shemiras einayim (guarding the eyes)? (halachas/mussar. something like the chafetz chaim's book on shemira halashon)

Comment: GuardYourEyes.com has a wealth of resources.

Comment: http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/32669  טהרת יום טוב also. This is in many volumes on the said book. Personally I dont believe in using such books or talking about these subjects they do more harm than good.

Comment: @preferred why harm?

Comment: Also: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65204 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53037

Answer (score 2):

Guard Your Eyes is an organization who is Moser Nefesh to help those who have moral values of today's world. They have great eBooks, you can see them [here](https://guardyoureyes.com/ebooks).