# Laws of Shemirat Einayim

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books, shemirat-eynayim

I'm looking for a comprehensive summary of the halachas of shemiras einayim (guarding the eyes).

I am not looking for those things which are *midat chasidut* (extra piety) but rather only those things which are binding halacha.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38771/5323

Comment: I took the small liberty of editing out the "please source" part of your question, because I didn't think it was relevant. What kind of sources would you be looking for, anyway? ....if I misunderstood the question, you can (of course) edit that part back in.

Comment: @Shokhet pretty useless without sources don't you think?

Comment: Well, shouldn't any book be able to speak for itself?

Comment: http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01662.html

Comment: Also: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65204