# Lectures on "Shemiras Einayim"

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, english, adult-learning, shemirat-eynayim

Would anyone know of any online lectures on the inyan of *Shemiras Einayim* in English ( preferably lectures that I could download. )

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38771 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53037

Answer (score 1):

go to this site, they have tons of resources: https://GuardYourEyes.com/